# XPath expression not finding element within ListRenderingProfileService

Tags: xml, xpath, websphere-portal

I have the following `XML` document being returned by a REST service ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root> 
  <grand>10</grand> 
</root>
```

I'm using `IBM Portal` (`WCM`) to render the parsed results, more specifically a new framework called `DDC` available in latest version of IBM Portal.
To parse `XML` responses `WebSphere` uses xpath to specify which elements are inserted into `AttributeResources` for use in `WCM`.

Using `//grand/text()` expression selects the text using an online xpath validator but when I use that expression as an `ItemAttribute` value in custom properties of `WP ListRenderingProfileService` , no result is found .. anyone any ideas?

Comment: Add tag for specific technology you're using. Your XPath should work fine against the XML, so the solution may need to be specific to the platform (the IBM Portal or something..)

Comment: Maybe the library only implements a sub set of the XPath specification. One obvious restriction may be the support of `//`. Have you tried if `/root/grand/text()` works?